# How do I request a certificate from CEP / CES on a Microsoft CA on OSX or Linux?

Tags: certificate, windows, linux, certificate-authority, mac-osx

This [article describes how to request a certificate](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2010/05/25/enabling-cep-and-ces-for-enrolling-non-domain-joined-computers-for-certificates.aspx) from AD CS (Active Directory Certificate Services) from a non-domain joined windows computer.

I would think the same principals apply to non Microsoft OS's, and it's possible to do the same enrollment from OSX or Linux.

**Question**

- How would I request a certificate from AD CS on OSX/Linux?
- OR can someone tell me how does the AD CS service work (in sufficient detail) so I can develop an alternate solution?

Answer (score 4):

I realize this is a bit old, but there is a solution now, using [certmonger](https://www.freeipa.org/page/Certmonger) + [cepces](https://github.com/openSUSE/cepces). If you want to auto enroll, you can [configure Group Policy in Samba](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Group_Policy) with [Certificate Auto Enrollment](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php?title=Certificate_Auto_Enrollment) (only available in Samba 4.15+).

For a simple setup, you would install [certmonger](https://www.freeipa.org/page/Certmonger) and [cepces](https://github.com/openSUSE/cepces), then modify /etc/cepces/cepces.conf for your environment. For a typical configuration, you'll just need to set the `server` parameter to the dns name of your Windows CA.

The rpm spec is supposed to run a script that adds the CA to certmonger. If not, then add it with `getcert add-ca -c cepces -e /usr/libexec/certmonger/cepces-submit`.

Then you can request your certificate, for example:

```
# getcert request -c cepces -T Machine -I MachineCertificate -k /etc/pki/tls/private/machine.key -f /etc/pki/tls/certs/machine.crt
New signing request "MachineCertificate" added.
```

Comment: FYI, this works on various Linux distros. I don't know whether anyone has ported certmonger to OSX.

Answer (score 2):

ADCS Enrollment Web Services utilize two communication protocols: [[MS-XCEP]](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd302869.aspx) and [[MS-WSTEP]](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd340609.aspx) (a Microsoft implementation of [[WS-TRUST]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WS-Trust) protocol).

CEP (implements [MS-XCEP]) is an enrollment policy service that is used to:

1. provide available to client certificate templates for enrollment.
2. provide Certificate Enrollment Service (CES) URIs

CES (implements [MS-WSTEP]) is an enrollment service that is used to:

1. submit certificate requests
2. retrieve issued certificates
3. provide an Enrollment On Behalf Of (EOBO) functionality

related protocol specifications may apply ([MS-ADTS] and [MS-CERTD], for instance).

I'm not aware about any compatible client for Linux OS, however there is a compatible module for Apple MacOS and iOS: http://www.zevainc.com/index.php/productsandtools/licensed-products/item/91-certdeploy

Answer (score 1):

> How would I request a certificate from AD CS on OSX/Linux?

If you don't need to automate this, then simply go with "Active Directory Certificate Services Web Enrollment". It's a simple little web app that (amongst other things) allows you to paste in arbitrary CSRs. It doesn't care whether they originate from a Windows OS.

A windows admin will then have to approve or deny that CSR manually and then find a way to give you that newly created cert. So that's for low volume throughput only.

Basic clicks listed here: http://www.whitneytechnologies.com/?p=218

Answer (score 1):

> How would I request a certificate from AD CS on OSX/Linux?

CEP and CES are services for manual and automated certification enrollment on Windows systems.

On Linux or similar systems the AD CS role *NDES (Network Device Enrollment Service)* is used.

This article should give you a good overview of the service: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/jeffbutte/2016/12/16/236/